# BackupBuddy WP CLI Invalid Profile Error

Tags: wp-cli

When I try to run a WordPress (3.8) backup of a site using wp-cli 10 alpha (site [here](http://wp-cli.org))

```
wp --info
PHP binary: /usr/local/bin/php-5.3
PHP version:    5.3.5
php.ini used:   /etc/php53/php.ini
wp-cli root:    /usr/local/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/
wp-cli config:  
wp-cli version: 0.10.0-alpha
```

on my Dreamhost VPS in combination with BackupBuddy 4.2.12.1 I get this error

```
wp backupbuddy backup profile-name
Error: Error #85489548955. Invalid profile ID not numeric: `profile-name`.
```

Any ideas how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the command using a number - 2 which is the full backup profile no - instead of the profile name it does run. So this problem has been solved.

As a side note. I then I get this error: zip warning permission denied . I also see:

```
error - Error #3382: Backup FAILED. Unable to successfully generate ZIP archive.
error - Error #3382 help: http://ithemes.com/codex/page/BackupBuddy:_Error_Codes#3382
haltScript - 
error - Failed function `backup_zip_files`. Backup terminated.
errorFunction - backup_zip_files
details - Peak memory usage: 42.82 MB
haltScript - 
error - Sending email error notification with subject `BackupBuddy Error - http://www.site.org` to recipient(s): `me@gmail.com`.
details - Completed step function `backup_create_database_dump`.
```

Seems like hoster Dreamhost stops he script whether I use the plugin from the backend or the WP CLI.

But this new error is not related to the question asked. That one is solved. Just use a profile number instead of the profile name